# Kopete: is there a way to disable desktop notification (the OSD Notify popups)?

Tags: linux, kopete, notify-osd

Kopete: is there a way to disable desktop notification (the OSD Notify popups)?

Kopete v0.70.2
KDE: 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto settings -> Notification, and uncheck popup notifications for all.

Comment: argh, that’s what you get for turning off menu bars. i searched in the settings dialog frantically, but didn’t realize that KDE has a separate notification settings dialogue (like it has for e.g. shortcuts, too)

Answer (score 1):

open kopete window then go to settings>Configure Notifications and select what you want kopete put in pop-ups xD

Answer (score 0):

there's also alternative notification system called Colibri

you can install it easy:

apt-get install colibri

http://gitorious.org/colibri/pages/SetupHowto

IMHO it's less annoying